# How to return all the records against an id in a web API get by id function

Tags: asp.net

Here is my get by id function that returns first or default row of the user account's table that matches the given town id, I want to return all the rows (users) that are having the given town id.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id) {
    using(KWSB_dbEntities entities = new KWSB_dbEntities()) {
        entities.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var entity = entities.User_Account.FirstOrDefault(e = > e.Town_Id == id);

        if (entity != null) {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, entity);
        } else {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "User_Account with Town id = " + id.ToString() + " not found ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just:

```
 var entity = entities.User_Account.FirstOrDefault(e = > e.Town_Id == id);
```

Needs to become

```
 var entity = entities.User_Account.Where(e = > e.Town_Id == id);
```

Difference being a where clause selects all the matching rows, firstordefault selects only the 1st matching one.

Comment: I tried the advice above and got this error on browser.

"$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'."

Answer (score 0):

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id) {
using(KWSB_dbEntities entities = new KWSB_dbEntities()) {
    entities.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    entities.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    var entity = entities.User_Account.FirstOrDefault(e = > e.Town_Id == id);

    if (entity != null) {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, entity);
    } else {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "User_Account with Town id = " + id.ToString() + " not found ");
    }
}
```

}